# Inject doesn't work with second constructor

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

for my current project I'm using Kotlin and Dagger 2.
I want to inject dependencies in an secondary constructor, but the constructor never gets initialized.

```
class SelectionFragmentModel ():ViewModel(){
   lateinit var channelInfosRepository: ChannelInfosRepository
   @Inject constructor(channelInfosRepository: ChannelInfosRepository) : this(){
      this.channelInfosRepository = channelInfosRepository
   }
   ...
}
```

As a workaround I'm currently injecting in the primary constructor but this isn't optimal.

```
class SelectionFragmentModel @Inject constructor(private val channelInfosRepository: ChannelInfosRepository):ViewModel(){
   constructor() : this(ChannelInfosRepository())
   ...
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: you mean  constructor that has no parameter?

Comment: The primary constructor should have no parameters and the injection should happen in the secondary constructor

Comment: in `Kotlin` this is not the case. check this from documentation `A class in Kotlin can have a primary constructor and one or more secondary constructors. The primary constructor is part of the class header: it goes after the class name (and optional type parameters)`

Comment: @user3517658 any solutions?

Comment: any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `SelectionFragmentModel` class **has only one constuctor**. It does not matter if the constructor is primary or secondary in terms of Kotlin language idioms. There will be only one constructor to use in `SelectionFragmentModel`.

The following code leaves no options for the initializer regarding which constructor to use as there is only one!

```
class SelectionFragmentModel: ViewModel {
    lateinit var channelInfosRepository: ChannelInfosRepository

    @Inject constructor(channelInfosRepository: ChannelInfosRepository) : super() {
        this.channelInfosRepository = channelInfosRepository
    }
}
```

#### Example (that works)

In this example we have default setup using dagger:

1. `@Module` annotated class that provides us with `ChannelInfosRepository`;
2. Modified `SelectionFragmentModel` (the code is located above the example);
3. Interface annotated with `@Component` with a list of modules consisting of only one module;
4. Everything else is just Android stuff.

Here is the module:

```
@Module
class AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesChannelInfosRepository(): ChannelInfosRepository {
        return ChannelInfosRepository()
    }
}
```

Interface annotated with `@Component`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(fragment: MainFragment)
}
```

Here is how the `AppComponent` is instantiated. `MyApplication` must be mentioned in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    var appComponent: AppComponent? = null
        private set

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(AppModule())
                .build()
    }
}
```

Fragment that injects `SelectionFragmentModel` using `AppComponent`:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var selectionFragmentModel: SelectionFragmentModel

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Ugly but fine for a test
        (activity?.application as? MyApplication)?.appComponent?.inject(this)
    }

    // onCreateView and other stuff ...

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        println("ViewModel address = ${selectionFragmentModel}")
        println("ChannelInfosRepository address = ${selectionFragmentModel.channelInfosRepository}")
    }
}
```

The result (instead of printing the result I displayed it in a TextView):

[image: The result of the code in example]